# ONESIGNAL Implement good use of tags in dynamic routes

Tags: reactjs, node.js, onesignal

I need a little help to be able to use onesignal in my project. Maybe there is no way to do it, so I ask you how it could be done. I'll try to be brief. I created a website where a user generates an invitation for their child's birthday, then shares the link to their guests (it is a dynamic route that will no longer be accessible after the birthday). When a guest accesses the link, onesignal goes into action, the guest is asked if they want to receive a birthday reminder one day before the birthday. If you access it, a tag is added with the birthday id {key:value}. Then from the backend a cron-job reads the birthday table and obtains the birthdays that are one day or less away, and notifications are generated for those tags. HERE is the problem, once the notifications are sent I can't find a way to know who the notifications were sent to in order to delete the tag that will never be used again.

I am currently exploring onesignal on the free plan... The backend is made in nodejs and express and the frontend with nextjs